# Why is Facebook suggesting friends with no connections to me?

Tags: facebook

Under the `People You May Know` section on the right side of the site, Facebook normally suggests people with a lot of mutual friends, helping me get connected with people that I probably know. However, I recently added several game-only friends (people who play a Facebook game that I play) which seems to have increased the range of this list. Occasionally, Facebook recommends that I add friends that some of the game-only friends have added, which is helpful for expanding my in-game network. However, it has also been suggesting that I add friends who have no friends in common with me.

Why is Facebook recommending complete strangers to me?

Comment: Perhaps you both worked for the same company at one time (although perhaps not simultaneously). Maybe you have a school in common. Maybe you live in the same town. Perhaps you share a lot of common interests.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but it could be friends of friends of friends. I worked for a social media company that did just that.

Comment: Considering they popped up as a started adding strangers to my friends list (whereas before, the list was only people with a lot of mutual friends), this very well may be the case.